# Find nodes with common connections

Tags: data-science, networkx, graph-theory, bipartite

At the moment, I've have created a bipartite networkx graph that maps Disorders to Symptoms. So, a disorder may be linked to one or more Symptoms.
Also, i have some basic statistics, like, Symptoms with at least one Disorder etc.

```
import networkx as nx

csv_dictionary = {"Da": ["A", "C"], "Db": ["B"], "Dc": ["A", "C", "F"], "Dd": ["D"], "De": ["E", "B"], "Df":["F"], "Dg":["F"], "Dh":["F"]}

G = nx.Graph()

all_symptoms = set()
for disorder, symptoms in csv_dictionary.items():
    for i in range (0, len(symptoms)):
        G.add_edge(disorder, symptoms[i])

        all_symptoms.add(symptoms[i])

symptoms_with_multiple_diseases = [symptom for symptom in all_symptoms if G.degree(symptom) > 1]

sorted_symptoms = list(sorted(symptoms_with_multiple_diseases, key= lambda symptom: 
G.degree(symptom)))
```

What i need is to find **Disorders that share at least two Symptoms**. So, Disorders that have two Symptoms in common with each other.
I've done some research and i think i should add weights for my edges, based on how they connect, but i cannot wrap my head around it.

So, in the above example, Da and Dc share two Symptoms ( A and C ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the length `2` combinations of the `disorder` nodes with a centrality higher than `2`, and find the [`nx.common_neighbours`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.common_neighbors.html) of each combination, keeping only those that share at least `2` neighbours.

So start instead by keeping track of all disorders too:

```
all_symptoms = set()
all_disorders = set()

for disorder, symptoms in csv_dictionary.items():
    for i in range (0, len(symptoms)):
        G.add_edge(disorder, symptoms[i])
        all_symptoms.add(symptoms[i])
    all_disorders.add(disorder)
```

Check which have a degree higher than `2`:

```
disorders_with_multiple_diseases = [symptom for symptom in all_disorders 
                                    if G.degree(symptom) > 1]
```

And then iterate over all `2` combinations of `all_dissorders`:

```
from itertools import combinations

common_symtpoms = dict()
for nodes in combinations(all_disorders, r=2):
    cn = list(nx.common_neighbors(G, *nodes))
    if len(cn)>1:
        common_symtpoms[nodes] = list(cn)
```

---

```
print(common_symtpoms)
# {('Da', 'Dc'): ['A', 'C']}
```